# Post Model to Controller in ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

This is My ajax Code

```
      $('#RolesSave').click(function () {
            var sRow = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($('#table').bootstrapTable('getSelections')));
            var ID = JSON.stringify(sRow, ["ID"]);

            var view = {
                CompanyCode: $('#Company').val(),
                RolesCode: $('#Roles').val(),
                ID,
            };

            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("Save")',
                data: $('#formData').serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data + '!!!')
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('ERROR')
                }
            })
        })
```

This is My Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Save(RightsModel view)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

and This My Model

```
public class RightsModel
{
    public List<string> ID { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Roles { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my view

```
<form id="formData">
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Company, Model.Company)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Roles, Model.Roles)
<button id="RolesSave" class="btn btn-primary btn-light" type="submit">存檔</button>
<table id="table"></table>
```

My problem is when I use the code $('#formData').serialize(). It can convert the data in View into Model normally.
But when I use JSON.serialize(view), It can't achieve the same goal.
Even if I add [FormBody] to the Action, I cannot get any relevant information.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.serialize` is not exists in js,we usually use `JSON.stringify`.And you need to make sure the model structure of view is the same with model `RightsModel`.And you need to add `contentType:"application/json",` to ajax since you want to pass json type data to action.Here is a demo:

js：

```
$('#RolesSave').click(function () {
           var sRow = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($('#table').bootstrapTable('getSelections')));
            var ID = [];
            sRow.forEach(function (item, index) {
                ID.push(""+item.ID);
            });
            var view = {
                Company: $('#Company').val(),
                Roles: $('#Roles').val(),
                ID: ID
            };
                $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("Save")',
                    data: JSON.stringify(view),
                    contentType:"application/json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data + '!!!')
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('ERROR')
                }
            })
        })
```

action:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Save([FromBody]RightsModel view)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

result:
[image]

I try yo use `var ID = ["1", "2", "3"];` to test,and it can work.ID need to be type `List<string>`.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I didn't write the method right.
But I have tried the method you provided.
As a result, the Model in the Controller is also null.
Unable to pass.

Comment: Can you share your value of `sRow` and `ID`,I use `var ID = ["1", "2", "3"];` to test,and it can work.ID need to be type `List<string>`.

Comment: The value of the JSON is
ID:"[{\"ID"\:1},{\"ID\":4}]"

Comment: You mean `JSON.stringify($('#table').bootstrapTable('getSelections'))` is ID:"[{\"ID"\:1},{\"ID\":4}]"?Or  ID is ID:"[{\"ID"\:1},{\"ID\":4}]"? Can you share your `sRow`?

Comment: I use JSON.stringify($('#table').bootrapTable('getSelections')) get the Select data is
[{"ID":1,"Value":"A1"},{"ID":4,"Value":"A2"}], but I only need ID value

Comment: I have updated my answer,you can try the updated code.

Comment: Use `var ID = [];sRow.forEach(function (item, index) {ID.push(""+item.ID); });` as the answer shown.